# Remove invalid SIDs from filesystem ACLs in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, access-control-list

Is there an automated way to traverse a filesystem and remove any ACL entries that reference invalid SIDs in any version of Windows with NTFS?

Answer (score 2):

icacls can do that:

ICACLS name [/grant[:r] Sid:perm[...]]
       [/deny Sid:perm [...]]
       [/remove[:g|:d]] Sid[...]] [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
       [/setintegritylevel Level:policy[...]]

```
    /remove[:[g|d]] Sid removes all occurrences of Sid in the ACL. With
    :g, it removes all occurrences of granted rights to that Sid. With
    :d, it removes all occurrences of denied rights to that Sid.
```

You can also check for bad entries:

> ICACLS name /verify [/T] [/C] [/L]
>   [/Q]
>       finds all files whose ACL is not in canonical form or whose
>       lengths are inconsistent with ACE counts.

Comment: FILEACL do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because I am running this on a 2003 server, but this does not produce useful results for me.

> ICACLS name /verify [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q] finds all files whose ACL is not in canonical form or whose lengths are inconsistent with ACE counts.

I'm not sure what that is supposed to do, but it doesn't provide anything useful for me. I have a folder with an unknown SID.

> ICACLS *foldername*

returns the ACL entries, including "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done". It does not tell me which SID it failed to get a mapping for.

> ICACLS *foldername* /verify

All this tells me is: "Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files". Sounds great, but what was the result of the processing?

I get the exact same results running this on any individual files in the folder as well. In order to remove the SIDs, you need to know what they are. And this is not a very helpful method for getting a list of the SIDs that need to be cleaned up.

Comment: Use 'accesschk.exe -lq filename'  (google 'accesscheck Russinovich'), to see complete ACL for path (100s of lines per filename). More help accesscheck -h.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ICACLS does not flag what I call **orphaned SID's** which were from trusted domains that the userid or group has been deleted. So when you view the Security tab in file properties in Explorer, you only see a SID and it does not resolve to the readable name of the user/group. Regardless I am of no help; I know of no automated way to remove these on a mass basis.

EDIT: Ok perhaps if you are gung ho, you could use ICACLS output, get orphans, cook up a script, test, then test more ...